# C# async method breaks application

Tags: c#, windows, asynchronous, methods, web

So I have an app that is retrieving web information. After I get this information I need to process the object returned (A JSON string).
However, as far as I can tell, my program keeps breaking as when the web info is awaiting, it jumps into the next processing stage, which has no data to process, therefore breaks.
How can I go about fixing it?

Here is the async method

```
    async private Task GetInformation(string url)
    {
        client = new HttpClient();

        response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

As mentioned below, I should have put await infront of the location where I am calling GetInformation, however, that method is used to return a string to another class like so

```
    public string GetResult(string url)
    {
        GetInformation(url);
        return result;
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe you can put a time limit for waiting response?

Comment: consider using ConfigureAwait(false) on task

Answer (score 3):

The place where you call `GetInformation(url)` must also have the `await` keyword:

```
// stage1
//... some code ...

// stage2
await GetInformation(url);

// stage3
//... some code ...
```

Without `await` your method launches the download but it runs in parallel with stage 3.

An alternative to the `await` for when you can't make that method `async` is to launch the task in another thread and wait for that thread to complete:

```
Task.Run(() => GetInformation(url)).RunSynchronously(); // use .Result if you have Task<T>
```

`Task.Run()` can be skipped if your code does not run on the UI thread - then just call `GetInformation(url).RunSynchronously()`. If it does run on UI thread then without `Task.Run` you risk deadlocks.

Your third option would be to use a locking mechanism like `ManualResetEvent`. If the previous approaches do not work, look for samples using this class.

Comment: And of course method calling `GetInformation` also has to be `async`

Comment: Okay that's great, however the method I call GetInformation is being used to return the result to another class. I updated the OP to show what I mean

Comment: @AndyOHart - that does not change anything - make that method `async`, then the method calling it etc. If you can't do that, I added an alternative to the answer.

Comment: I made GetResult async and had it return a type of Task<string>, however, when I try set the string to this, it says it can't be a type of Task.string.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
private async Task<string> GetInformation(string url)
{
    client = new HttpClient();

    response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

And use as following:

```
var task = GetInformation(url);
DoSomeStuffInParallelWithDownload();
var result = task.Result;
UseDownloadResult(result);
```

Comment: `await` and `task.Result` does not quite go together - your code will not compile...